# How do I get organized with Oracle SQL scripts when switching from old fashion SQL Plus to SQL Developer with modern GUI interface?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, version-control, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used to work on SQL scripts under SQLPlus environment using putty from MS Windows.   All source scripts are in the same file directory. But it doesn't have color syntax or good editor. SQL Developer has all that. Now I started using SQL Developer under Windows environment.  The down side is my SQL scripts and coworker's (one or two, not too many) scripts scattered around in each person's PC.  My temporary solution is copy the file back to the same Unix file directory using Winscp utiltiy.  Any one has better idea?  Samba file sharing? And Version control?

Oracle's Application Express (APEX) put SQL script within workspace which has user access right management.  Is that the solution?  But some of my scripts are for nightly batch jobs, not in this category.

Comment: Where are the files?  You suggest that they are on unix then state they are on local machines.

Comment: Files should be stored in Unix file system so they can get executed by  cronjob (shell script will call these SQL scripts and output log files to predefined location).  But I get more productive creating scripts under SQL developer which is similar to MS SQL management studio or other party's GUI tool like Toad from Quest.  SQL Plus is a command line development environment by default using VI editing syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement them in PL/SQL, compile them in the database and run them there. I would store a copy of all scripts in a project in a source control system like git or subversion. Anyone needing to use the scripts will already have them available in the db. Anyone needing to modify them will be able to easily get the latest version of all scripts.

Comment: Thanks for commenting!  But with GUI interface of SQL Developer, it is far more productive than plain SQL Plus vi interface (no color syntax). And I believe GUI interface is the future.  Anyone who developed modern software would view SQL+ as stoneage developer tool.

Comment: Probably it doesn't work in a way that's useful for you but once you compile the PL/SQL procedures in the database you can access them in SQL Developer from the tree control in the left panel under Packages or Procedures (depending on how you structure your PL/SQL), and they'll be accessible to anyone who accesses the database with no need to have a local copy of the script.

Comment: I see your points now, by store the script as package/stored procedure, the script is available to anyone who accesses the database. No local copy is needed.